# Generate package with source code for debug

Tags: android, intellij-idea, jar

How can I package (JAR) an Android Library on IntelliJ Idea with the source embedded for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually done by creating two JARs: one with .class files for execution and another with .java source for debugging.

Comment: Ok, but, how do I create them on IntelliJ? The default maven package command generates only one jar file without sources

Comment: ask intellij to create jar artifacts - one with .class, another with .java.  forget about maven.

Comment: The option to generate artifacts is greyed out on menu

Comment: You are right. Any other option instead of buying the enterprise version ? Thanks

Comment: Sure, use the jar.exe in a command shell.  You don't need an IDE for this simple thing.